# Configuring Quartz Jobs to run on specific machine

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am using quartz 2.2.0. I want to configure IP address with each job and want to check that each job runs on the machine configured to it. 
I can check it manually while starting the job on server startup, but do we have any configuration parameter to configure the job like this? so that I can reduce coding.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you find anything related to this? I'm pretty much looking for something similar.